# How to add assign csrf token in the HTML submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csrf

My site is under csurf protection at the moment.

I have assigned all my ajax call with csrf token like below

`"/data/someAPI?_csrf="+ $("#_csrf").val` and it works just fine with all function I had.

But now I am writing a file upload function and most of the tutorials on the internet are using sumbit form to do so.

So I wrote something like

**Node.js**

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.files)
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

  // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
  let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
  sampleFile.mv('/somewhere/on/your/server/filename.jpg', function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});
```

**Solved**

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form ref='uploadForm' 
      id='uploadForm' 
      action='http://localhost:8000/upload?_csrf=<your_csrf_token>"' 
      method='post' 
      encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
        <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
    </form>     
  </body>
</html>
```

I directly assigned the token in the form action and it works fine.

Comment: Why not do it as you are doing in `ajax` call? i.e. define token in form `action`.

Comment: @aquaman do you mean i should  <input type='hidden' name='form-control' value='{{_csrf}}'> put this line within the form?

Comment: I meant modify your form as `action="/upload?_csrf=<your_csrf_token>"`. And well what you suggested in another option you can try.

Comment: thanks i solved it!!! @aquaman

Comment: Quick question, how do you obtain that CSRF token in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add hidden field for `_csrt` token. Here is example code

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form ref='uploadForm' 
      id='uploadForm' 
      action='http://localhost:8000/upload' 
      method='post' 
      encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<your_csrf_token>" />
        <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
    </form>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BhavaniSolanki : After implementing CSRF solution hidden field comparing server side , the problem is , when open new tab with same URL then hidden filed comes null.Server side condition is if CSRF hidden field null then its attack.is it expected behavior ?