# Cannot retrieve data from endpoint

Tags: python, django

I have installed [Chatterbot](http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/django/index.html) for Django integration. I followed the easy tutorial with every step and made it so that the endpoint was: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/chatterbot/` What I did next was try to communicate with that endpoint to see if I would get back any results. So I made an Ajax request as follows:

```
var query = {"text": "My input statement"};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/chatterbot/",
    data: JSON.stringify(query),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

However, what returns in console is: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/chatterbot/ 403 (Forbidden)` and what returns in the cmd prompt when I run my server is:

> csrf: WARNING - Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):
>   /chatterbot/ [29/Mar/2018 02:16:43] "POST /chatterbot/ HTTP/1.1" 403
>   2502

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it so I receive the call back from the endpoint?

**View for this page:**

```
def IndexView(request):
    latest_questions = Questions.objects.all().order_by("-date_published")[:5]
    popular_questions = Questions.objects.all().order_by("-num_replies")[:5]

    return render(request, 'core/index.html',
                  {'latest_questions': latest_questions, 'popular_questions': popular_questions
                   })
```

Comment: can i see your controller or view ?

Comment: you can fix this with a simple decorator.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar I updated it with the view, also how do you fix it with a decorator?

Comment: i add an answer. csrf_exempt decorator remove requirements of csrf token from your service. update me if it didnt work.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/ Please follow the link.You will get enough idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

var query = {
   "text": "My input statement",
   "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/chatterbot/",
    data: query,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

one way is to send the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` like below

```
    var query = {
       "text": "My input statement",
       'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{csrf_token }}"
    };
```

other way is to use `@csrf_exempt` decorator

```
  from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

  @csrf_exempt
  def IndexView(request):
     # .... code.....
```

other is to add a script

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/

Comment: It doesn't work with the first way. It still gives me the same error. Also for the second way it tells me `csrftoken` is undefined.

Comment: @user2896120 use `csrf_exempt` decorator

Comment: The IndexView is just a view to my page. I am using a package for the endpoint

Comment: I am still getting the same error for some reason. Could you try to install the package? It's very simple, try it and see if you get the same thing

Comment: @user2896120  according django docs it should work. try your luck :)

Comment: Like I said, it's not working. I am getting a 500 internal server error

Comment: When I remove: `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in settings.py middleware, the code above starts working. I don't know why it doesn't work with it..

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use CSRF tokens just add this above your code.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def IndexView(request):
    # your code
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I am using a package. The IndexView is just a view for my site, but I am using an installed endpoint

Comment: oh! then you should add csrf token to request header.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527120/how-to-add-assign-csrf-token-in-the-html-submit-form?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: use above link for your html file. then get the value and add it to request header before you send it to server.

Comment: But this isn't a form, this is a REST endpoint http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/django/index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167787/discussion-between-mehrdad-pedramfar-and-user2896120).

Comment: When I remove this in settings.py middleware: ` 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` It starts working properly